# How to get standard deviation across multiple 2d arrays by cell?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, standard-deviation

I have 16 2d-arrays, each in a shape of [16000, 16000], which means one array has 256000000 cells. I want to have a std_array that is the standard deviation of each cell in the 16 arrays. I tried something but failed, and **my questions are in bold.**

Here's my attempt. For example (simplified 3*3 arrays):

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
b = np.array([[2,3,4],[2,3,4],[2,3,4]])
c = np.array([[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[3,4,5]])

stack = np.vstack((a,b,c))
var = np.std(stack, axis = 0)
```

However, the np.std function **only returns 3 values, but I want 9. What should I do?**

```
[0.81649658 0.81649658 0.81649658]
```

In addition, when I apply std on the stacked-arrays, **I get this error. Does it simply mean that my arrays are too large to operate?**

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (256000, 16000) and data type float32
```

Comment: So did you try: `np.std(stack, axis = 1)`?  This will produce your 9 values. The error is telling you that you don't have enough memory to make an array with 4 billion floating point values.

Comment: The array you try to allocate takes 30 GiB so it is pretty big. Not to mention the initial array also takes 30 GiB resulting in 60 GiB of memory needed. You could compute the std without building such huge array but your needs are not very clear to me: what do you mean by "*standard deviation of each cell in the 16 arrays*"?. Can you clarify this a bit?

Comment: @JérômeRichard saying I have 256000000 cells(values) in each array and I have 16 arrays, I want the final std_array to be the same shape (16000*16000, which equals 256000000 cells), and each cell is the std of the 16 cells in that position in the 16 arrays. I hope this clarifies the confusion.

Comment: thank you @Mark. Yes, axis=1 solves the issue, although it still has the memory issue which I expected.

Comment: Ok. In this case, just using `axis=1` does not match your needs. In fact, `np.vstack` create a 2D array while I think you expect a 3D array and `axis=0` to be used (on this 3D array). Unfortunately, in this example, this give the same result, but not in other array like random data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `np.vstack((a,b,c))` just stack all lines of each array resulting in this one:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Computing the standard deviation along the axis 0 or 1 does not meet your requirements.

Instead, you can add a new dimension to each array so to stack them in a new dimension:

```py
stack = np.vstack([a[None], b[None], c[None]])
stack.std(axis=2)
```

In this case `stack` is:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],   <-- array `a`
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[2, 3, 4],   <-- array `b`
        [2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4]],

       [[3, 4, 5],   <-- array `c`
        [3, 4, 5],
        [3, 4, 5]]])
```

The result is a 2D array of shape `(3,3)` where the standard deviation is computed based on the 3 values coming from respectively each of the 3 arrays.

The thing is building a huge array so to reduce it later is not memory efficient. You can instead iterate over the lines so to build smaller arrays:

```py
result = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=np.float64)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    stacked_line = np.vstack([a[i, None], b[i, None], c[i, None]])
    result[i,:] = stacked_line.std(axis=0)
```

For higher performance, you can use *Numba* so to avoid the creation of many big arrays (mandatory with Numpy) that are expensive to build and fill.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. Everthing before iterating a result array worked fine. But when I try to iterate, the result is no longer correct. Instead of nine 0.816s, it gives nine 0s. Could you please help on this?

Comment: Ha, you are totally right! In your example `a` is an int-based array while in my tests I used a float-based array. `empty_like` create an int-based array and setting float values to it cause truncations. I fixed this. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I tried np.empty after I commented yesterday and it worked fine - although I didn't know why. Thanks for explaining it by chance ;)